# In JSP how do I make a GET request on selection of one dropdown value and get data for other dropdowns from DB?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Hi All please suggest me some approaches for the below problem
Spring boot MVC: UI page is JSP
Currently All dropdown values are getting from DB when the home page is opened 
I am stuck at the below task
On selection of one dropdown value, the below other dropdown values should be auto populated in jsp before the form is submitted
How do I make a GET request on selection of one dropdown value and get data for other dropdowns from DB?
below is the sample jsp form
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgdGH.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you using jquery with jsp then , use Ajax POST in Change event of name-3 dropdown , on success function populate on name-4 , name-5 drop down.

Like,

```
$(document).on('change','#name3',function(){

            callAjaxByObj({
                "url"   : "url",
                "type"  : "POST",
                "data"  : {"name3Id" : $(this).val()},
                "resp"  : afterSuccess(),
                "error" : ajaxFailed()
            });
    });
function afterSuccess(){
 return function(resp){
   // here you can populate Selected data on name-4, name-5 dropdowns use below
   $("#name4").val(resp.name4Id);
   $("#name5").val(resp.name5Id);

   // OR if you want to append new drop down values to append name4, name5 dropdowns 

    var htm='';
            var index = 0;
            var obj = '';
            for(index = 0; index < resp.name4List.length; index++) {
                obj =   resp.name4List[index];

                htm +='<option value="'+obj.id+'" >'+obj.name+'</option>';
            }
            $("#name4").append(htm);

    // same way you can do for name5 drop down.



 }
}
```